# Rotating a UIView that is added to keyWindow

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, rotation, uiwindow

I am designing an iOS Passcode Lock library with a "cover view" feature, which hides the content on the screen, when the app is backgrounded. See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoKsf.png).

When my `PasscodeManager` receives the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification, it does this:

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow addSubview:self.coverView];
```

This works great, does exactly what I want to do! However, if the iPad is in landscape orientation, this view does not rotate, and looks horrible on the iOS 7 multitasking preview interface.

I know that `UIViewController` handles rotations, but I am not sure how to use it for this purpose, because I can't seem to push a UIViewController when the app is getting backgrounded (it looks like 2 view controllers are on top of each other, each half visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewController` takes care of rotating its view.  If you are adding subviews directly to the window, you don't get that behavior.  So, you have two choices: either use a `UIViewController`, or handle the rotation yourself.  If you want to handle it yourself you can listen for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`. You may also need to call `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: It is impossible to use two view controllers with one window. There is only one root view controller. Also, why listen to device orientation when there is `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`? Still, this is a messy way and not recommended.

Comment: First of all, it's totally possible using UIViewController containment. Second, I didn't say use two at a time. I just said if you want free rotation, use a UIViewController. I didn't specify how. If I were doing it, I would swap out the rootViewController.

Comment: Thanks jsd. I think I will go ahead and use the swapping of the rootViewController method as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add subviews to the key window. This is messy, you will not hear orientation changes and you will not hide alert views and other elements displayed in different windows.

Instead, display another window with a higher window level (such as `UIWindowLevelAlertView`). This view will have its own view controller, which will hear all rotation notifications normally.

Take a look at my [`LNWindowManager`](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNWindowManager) helper class. You can use it as a much simplified API for presenting and dismissing windows on top of other windows. When you app enters the background, display the lock window with no animation. When the user unlocks, dismiss it with animation.